# Swagger was showing 'can't parse JSON. Raw result:' in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui

While trying to return the response in spring boot through swaggger it was showing something like this 'can't parse JSON.  Raw result:'

Answer (score 0):

From the info available, looks like the response returned is not in JSON format, but swagger is expecting it in JSON format. Check the response and the response headers.